# Why does the opencv cvtColor modify image sizes?

Tags: image, opencv, colors, yuv, color-space

I expect this to have more to do with color spaces and their attributes. I was attempting to convert a YUYV to a grayscale image. I used the following function call:

`cv::cvtColor(imgOrig, imgGray, cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_420);`

With this function, I lost some of the height of the image. I could obviously use the resize method to make the original image large enough such that the conversion wouldn't cut out any actual data, but wanted to find out the more appropriate way to go about it.

Looking at the opencv source, below is an excerpt from the cvtColor method:

```
case COLOR_YUV2GRAY_420:
        {
            if (dcn <= 0) dcn = 1;

            CV_Assert( dcn == 1 );
            CV_Assert( sz.width % 2 == 0 && sz.height % 3 == 0 && depth == CV_8U );

            Size dstSz(sz.width, sz.height * 2 / 3);
            _dst.create(dstSz, CV_MAKETYPE(depth, dcn));
            dst = _dst.getMat();
#ifdef HAVE_IPP
#if IPP_VERSION_X100 >= 201700
            if (CV_INSTRUMENT_FUN_IPP(ippiCopy_8u_C1R_L, src.data, (IppSizeL)src.step, dst.data, (IppSizeL)dst.step,
                                               ippiSizeL(dstSz.width, dstSz.height)) >= 0)
                break;
#endif
#endif
            src(Range(0, dstSz.height), Range::all()).copyTo(dst);
        }
        break;
```

You see that on the 8th line, the size of the destination image is made to be two-thirds the size of the source image.

Why is this so? What is the appropriate way to do a color space conversion?

Comment: [This](http://answers.opencv.org/question/100149/how-to-get-y-u-v-from-image/) may provide some explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plainly, it is how YUV420 works. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Converting_between_Y.E2.80.B2UV_and_RGB), YUV uses 6 bytes to store 4 pixels. Those 4 pixels share `U, V` values while having their own Y values. The picture and the formula presented in the [conversion from YUV420 to RGB888 section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.E2.80.B2UV420p_.28and_Y.E2.80.B2V12_or_YV12.29_to_RGB888_conversion) explains it better. They also explain very well why the check

`CV_Assert( sz.width % 2 == 0 && sz.height % 3 == 0 && depth == CV_8U );`

and why the RGB's is only `2/3` of the YUV's.

Comment: But if we're going to grayscale, wouldn't Y (luma) be the only thing that is necessary? Or does a grayscale conversion need to go through RGB  first?

Comment: Well, then it is even clearer that the luma size is 2/3 of the original YUV image, isn’t it?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but each pixel has it's own Y value, so the conversion to grayscale should be as easy as just ignoring the u/v (color information) and converting the Ys to levels.

Comment: The thing is, for YUV space, U and V are counted towards the dimensions of the image (at least in OpenCV). That’s why the channel number and depth for a YUV are 1 and CV_8U respectively. Similarly, if we forced depth of a BGR image to 1, the ‘width’ would be three times the real width.

Comment: Oh my. This is starting to make perfect sense. So basically, from the wiki article, YUV has the first set of bytes is luma. for a Z by Y image, the first Z\*Y bytes is Y (luma), the next Z\*Y/2 bytes are the color information (u and v). This essentially means that by taking 2/3 of the image, you are cutting out the u and v since for all YUV formats, they are stored at the end! So it changes the size of the Mat structure, but not the size of the pixel size of the actual image?

Comment: Basically, yes.